# How do I stop call log syncing back after iOS erase and install?

Tags: ios, icloud, data-synchronization, call

I have been having this issue for quite some time now:

After I restore my iPhone to factory settings and signed in my iCloud account, the call logs would come back mysteriously, even ones dating back a few months that I have deliberately deleted.

This is really scary if you think about it.

There does not seem to be anyone else asking this particular question.

How may I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the call data isn't coming from the carrier? If you don't sign in to iCloud it's highly unlikely that's the source of the data showing up again, no?

Comment: Call logs are coming back after I sign in iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't. Not yet anyway. Apple hasn't added a switch for it so as long as you connect to your iCloud account, the call log is going to sync.